# What is the correct method to include "<uapi/..>" directory in ArchLinux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, header-files, archlinux

My OS is `ArchLinux`, and write a simple program which just includes `<uapi/linux/ptrace.h>`:

```
#include <uapi/linux/ptrace.h>

void main(void) {}
```

The compilation complains:

```
test.c:1:10: fatal error: uapi/linux/ptrace.h: No such file or directory
#include <uapi/linux/ptrace.h>
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I check `/ust/include/uapi` directory, and find it is empty. Finally, I find the correct `uapi` position is `/usr/lib/modules/4.11.9-1-ARCH/build/include/uapi`. So what is the canonical way of using `<uapi/linux/..>` in `ArchLinux`? Create a new link which points to `/usr/lib/modules/4.11.9-1-ARCH/build/include/uapi` or put the path into `C_INCLUDE_PATH`? They all seem a little weird.

Comment: Maybe try `#include <sys/ptrace.h>`. What function are your trying to use from `ptrace`? Usually you can `man 3 XXX`, and it will bring up information on the function XXX from section 3 of the manual. Section 3 of the manual is *Library Functions*. Section 2 may also apply, which is *System Calls*. If all else fails, just try `man XXX`. In your case, try `man ptrace`, which may tell you to use `<sys/ptrace.h>`.

Comment: @jww Actually, I just want to do a test. Because I read some eBPF related scripts using `<uapi/linux/ptrace.h>`, but I find it is indeed an empty directory. So I am curious how to include it.

Comment: Unsure about ARCH, but for "normal" Linux distro `uapi/` headers should be installed for user **separately** from kernel ones. What you have under `/usr/lib/modules/4.11.9-1-ARCH/build/include/uapi` are headers for *kernel*. If you have Linux kernel `4.11.9-1-ARCH` installed from some ARCH repository, you probably need to update your `libc` library, so it will contain `uapi` headers for given kernel.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - Forgive my ignorance, I've never worked with UAPI... What is the actionable item? Do you install `uapi-dev{el}`? Or is it part of glibc, so `glibc-dev{el}` needs to be installed? Or maybe something else?

Comment: I seems get the answer: `<uapi/linux/ptrace.h>` is just used for building kernel module, and it is included in `/usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/...`. But my program is a user-space program, so it will search `/usr/include/uapi`, but it is empty directory, and it should be OK.

Comment: @jww: `uapi` headers for user programs comes with `libc` library (`glibc-dev` package, you are right).

Comment: It is as simple as removing *uapi/* part from the inclusion, i.e. *#include <linux/ptrace.h>*

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: `pacman -S linux-api-headers` and `#include <linux/ptrace.h>`

---

UAPI stands for User API and is the name of a folder in the kernel sources that is intended to be copied to an installation as part of the user-accessible kernel headers. In the case of Arch, some of these headers are copied to `/usr/include/linux/` (plus some generated files on kernel compilation). But this is not part of the default install, it is actually separated in a different package: `linux-api-headers` (after installing, you can use `#include <linux/ptrace.h>`).

There is no `/usr/include/uapi` and this is by design, the contents of the original uapi folder are directly copied into `/usr/include`.

So, unless you are programming a kernel module, what you are probably looking for is `#include <linux/ptrace.h>`.